# Python: How to deal with expected a readable buffer object in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am quitenew to python and I am working on a python script I inherited from someone I work with, and I am getting this error:

```
expected a readable buffer object
```

The code causing this is:

```
self.y_NoShock_data = np.zeros((self.a_count+1,1,self.numberOfTags+1,lookback+forward,),dtype=enums.    
self.y_data = np.zeros((self.a_count+1,len(self.SCL)+1,self.numberOfTags+1,lookback+forward,),dtype=enums.DataPoints)

self.y_NoShock_cum_data = np.zeros_like(self.y_NoShock_data)
self.y_cum_data = np.zeros_like(self.y_data)
```

enums.DataPoints looks like this:

```
enums.DataPoints = dtype([
        ('Amount','float32'),
        ])
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
Internal Server 

Error: /smCore/entity/1/runScenarioManager/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/bentaliadoros/Documents/workspace/LivingSvnAmmar/trunk/ScenarioManagerStandAlone/smCore/views/createScenario.py", line 445, in runScenarioManager
    a = ScenarioExecutionController(sEA)
  File "/Users/bentaliadoros/Documents/workspace/LivingSvnAmmar/trunk/ScenarioManagerStandAlone/smCore/models/scenarioExecutionController.py", line 176, in __init__
    shockEventDataSet=[], lookback=self.lookback, forward=self.forward, period=self.period) #,
  File "/Users/bentaliadoros/Documents/workspace/LivingSvnAmmar/trunk/ScenarioManagerStandAlone/smCore/models/scenarioExecution.py", line 307, in buildSeedScenarioObject
    cls.updateScenarioParameters(shockContainerList,shockEventDataSet, shockEventDateList)
  File "/Users/bentaliadoros/Documents/workspace/LivingSvnAmmar/trunk/ScenarioManagerStandAlone/smCore/models/scenarioExecution.py", line 130, in updateScenarioParameters
    self.initialiseResultArrays()
  File "/Users/bentaliadoros/Documents/workspace/LivingSvnAmmar/trunk/ScenarioManagerStandAlone/smCore/models/scenarioExecution.py", line 154, in initialiseResultArrays
    self.y_NoShock_cum_data = np.zeros_like(self.y_NoShock_data,dtype=enums.DataPoints)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 116, in zeros_like
    res.fill(0)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

He was working on a pc and I am on a Mac.
I've been looking around but can't find a solution for this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is `enums.DataPoints`?

Comment: The code in your traceback does not match the code you posted.  In the traceback, `dtype` is specified (as the type @Jaime has asked about), but not in the code you posted at the top.  Be sure you've saved (and reloaded if interactive) your source file if you've made changes.

Comment: I added enums.DataPoints, thanks

Comment: this results in this error: `_p = np.empty(1, dtype=[('p', np.uint16), ('pr', np.uint16)])` then `_p[:]=1` but not this: `_p = np.empty(2, dtype=[('p', np.uint16), ('pr', np.uint16)])` then `_p[:]=1`, looks like a bug to me (1.8.2)

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to respond without knowing what the `enums.DataPoints` dtype object looks like, but I'll try to explain where you see that error message.

When you try to set (an element of) an array to some value that doesn't align properly with its dtype, you will see this.  Here is an example:

```
In [133]: data = np.zeros((3,2), dtype="int, int")

In [134]: data
Out[134]: 
array([[(0, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])

In [135]: data[0, 0]
Out[135]: (0, 0)

In [136]: data[0, 0] = [1,2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-399e78675be4> in <module>()
----> 1 data[0, 0] = [1,2]

TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

This gave an error because it can't handle two values being assigned to one element of your array.  Your dtype has two values in it, so it seems reasonable to expect, but the array wants one object of type given by the dtype:

```
In [137]: data[0,0] = (1,2)

In [138]: data
Out[138]: 
array([[(1, 2), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 0)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

It's likely that a single set of zeros of the same shape of your array won't align with the dtype.

Comment: The code runs fine on the machines (Windows 7) of my colleagues. From askewchan's answer I'm not clear why the issue is arising especially since we're using numpy.zeros_like() -- From the documentation, this should basically replicate the prior array?

Comment: Yeah, it runs fine on my computer (python 2.7, numpy 1.7) too, now that I've set `DataPoints` as you added.  What version of numpy/python are you running?

Comment: I am using numpy version 1.6.1 and python 2.7.2

Comment: Thanks for this help, I found out that my numpy was out of date, I updated to 1.8.0 and the error is now gone. Thanks

Comment: Great, @Ben.  If that answers your question, please either accept mine or add your own and accept it, to mark the question as answered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was that I was not working under the same version of Numpy that my colleagues were using, as pointed out by @askewchan in the comments to his answer.

- Failed: numpy 1.6.1
- Works: numpy 1.7
- Works: numpy 1.8.0